# MySql- Select DISTINCT value from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have three tables and I want to SELECT DISTINCT * from table1 and cat from table2 of those whose vid is available in table3.

**Table1**

```
id      fname       area       price

1       ABC         Mall R     1500
2       ABd         Mall a     1400
3       ABe         Mall f     1200
4       ABt         Mall b     1000
```

**Table2**

```
id      catid       cat

1         2         xy
2         2         yz
3         1         yxx
4         4         ytt
5         3         xy
```

**Table3**

```
id       vid

1         2
2         1
3         4
```

So far what i have tried is

```
SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2,Table3 
WHERE 
Table1.id=Table2.catid AND
Table1.id=Table3.vid;
```

**Output i am getting**

```
id      fname       area       price     cat

1       ABC         Mall R     1500      yxx
2       ABd         Mall a     1400      xy
2       ABd         Mall a     1400      yz
4       ABt         Mall b     1000      ytt
```

**Desired Output**

```
id      fname       area       price     cat

1       ABC         Mall R     1500      yxx
2       ABd         Mall a     1400      xy
4       ABt         Mall b     1000      ytt
```

I want to select details of ID 2 just once doesn't matter it takes cat from Table2 "xy or yz".

Thanks....

Comment: you could use a max or min on the cat or vid, but it seems the keys aren't really strong enough to this effectively

Comment: You can always just `GROUP BY Table1.id` ... maybe

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks working for me....

Comment: On what basis are you distinguishing 'xy' from 'yz' as the `cat` value you want to obtain for `id` 2?  They seem equally viable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't have to show cat value. I need it for href only. Also it will take user to the same page for both cat values.

Answer (score 4):

Now using modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax, and table aliases.

The sub-query is there to return only each catid's max cat value.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.fname, t1.area, t1.price, t2.cat
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (select catid, max(cat) cat from Table2 group by catid) t2 ON t1.id = t2.catid 
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.vid
```

I don't see why you include Table3 in your query. You can probably remove the last JOIN and still get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a very simple, you can get your desire output without join query. And it is wiser using simple query instead of using join query. Because it is faster and not complex. If you don't need serial wise id you can ignore `order by t1.id`. And ignoring `order by` also wiser if it is not required. Hope it will help you.

```
 SELECT t1.id,t1.fname,t1.area,t1.price,t2.cat 
 FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2, table3 as t3 
 WHERE t1.id = t2.catid and t2.catid = t3.vid 
 group by t1.id order by t1.id
```